# How to create indexes for $or for array values

Tags: mongodb

Can someone please help me create an index for the below MongoDB query?

And also, please advise me after creating an index for this query, would improve the query performance.

```
db.sale.find({
        "$or": [
              {
                    "startDate": {
                          "$gte": ISODate("2022-05-29T00:00:00Z"),
                          "$lte": ISODate("2022-05-29T00:00:00Z")                       
                    }
              },
              {
                    "payments.paymentDate": "29-May-2022"
              }
        ],
        "account": ObjectId("5995488d9230ca34b70701bb"),
        "store": ObjectId("5995488d9230ca34b70701b9"),
        "payments.paymentType": "credit_card",
        "payments.serviceCardType": "visa",
})
```

Note: payments are an array of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no example document and we dont know the use cases , I can only bet that the best index here is compound index with following fields and order:

```
       {account:1 , store:1 , "payements.paymentDate":1,startDate:1}
```